# Extarct lat/lon of shiping line from geotiff file?

Tags: python, geopandas, geotiff

I download the geotiff dataset of marine shipping lines(Under the guidance of this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104450/what-are-the-existing-datasets-of-world-maritime-routes/104454)). The file had 194M and named `raw_2008_shipping_mol_20150714093538`.

I searched various answers on Google and Stack Overflow. For Now even I could transform all the points in geotiff to lat/lon on earth(Projection='cartopy.PlateCarree())' but still did't know how to extract the latlon of shipping lines. Any Can help me?

Comment: File description says that it is an ESRI Shapefile - a format for vector data as one would expect, however the file itself is a GeoTIFF generated with ERDAS Imagine - a raster. Probably this is a wrong file. Contact the publisher.

Comment: Using raster was probably practical for the purpose of the study of human impacts on ocean ecosystems, but to extract the shipping routes you'd rather search elsewhere.